# Reorganize my JSON Object in Javascript by Attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I got one problem. I receive this kind of json file from my web backend directly from my database. But in case of structure i want it to structure it on the client side to keep database access and http requests low. Each Element in this Array represents one dataset which has an sub-Category called 'sub' and main category called 'main'. Because I am working with AngularJS i want to display them in different elements with ng-repeat. Therefore I want to reorganize the structure of this json, so I got an Array of Main Categories which have an Array of Subcategories which have the data in them (also an Array).

```
 [
   {name: 'A', ..., sub: 'sub1', main: 'main1'},
   {name: 'B', ..., sub: 'sub1', main: 'main1'},
   {name: 'C', ..., sub: 'sub2', main: 'main1'},
   {name: 'D', ..., sub: 'sub3', main: 'main2'},
   ....
]
```

should be reorganized to the following:

```
[
   main1 : [
               sub1 : [    
                  {name: 'A', ...},
                  {name: 'B', ...}
               ],
               sub2 : [
                  {name: 'C', ...}
               ]
           ],
   main2 : [
               sub3 : [
                  {name: 'D', ...}

               ]
           ]
]
```

I have programmed some kind of solutions with many loops iterate through the array, memorize all the sub Categories and Main Categories and so on, but the main problem is by creating these arrays called main1 and main2 ( then sub1 and sub2, sub3). The Problem is that I couldn't find an soloution to name these Arrays since they are based on the string values from my "input data".

```
...
var subValue = .... (get name of sub category)
var result.push({subValue: []});
...
```

This don't work. All Array Elements are called subValue and not the name I want to be set.

I hope I can get some kind of related informations.

Answer (score 0):

Your requested output is impossible because array members are not object properties. There is no "key:value" in arrays. `main1` is an array, and it can contain values, but not keys (so you can't generate `main1: [ sub1:...`)

Either use an object instead of array, or have an array of values without keys

P.S., you should have a look at [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or a similar library that will do most of the heavy lifting for you

Comment: Well obviously OP got a little off track but this is not `impossible` ... it just needs a minor modification

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the output your looking for:

```
{
    main1 : {
        sub1 : [    
              {name: 'A', ...},
              {name: 'B', ...}
           ],
        sub2 : [ {name: 'C', ...} ]
    }, 
    main2 : {
        sub3 : [ {name: 'D', ...} ]
    }
}
```

You can solve this using underscore with two group by's

```
var arr = [
    {name: 'A', sub: 'sub1', main: 'main1'},
    {name: 'B', sub: 'sub1', main: 'main1'},
    {name: 'C', sub: 'sub2', main: 'main1'},
    {name: 'D', sub: 'sub3', main: 'main2'}
];

var grouped = _.chain(arr)
           .groupBy('main')
           .mapObject(function(item) { return _.groupBy(item, 'sub');})
           .value();
```